# Issue in plotting a 3D graph, error cannot reshape array of cannot reshape array of size 712 into shape (712,3)

Tags: python, numpy, 3d

I am having issue in plotting a 3D graph. I have csv file consisting of 713 rows and 3 columns

```
data = np.genfromtxt("graph-data.csv", delimiter=",", names=["x", "y","z"])
x, y, z = zip(*data)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('CPU availability(%)')
ax.set_ylabel('Memory availability(%)')
ax.set_zlabel('Frame Drop Rate(%)')
ax.plot_surface(np.array(x).reshape(712,3), np.array(y).reshape(712,3), np.array(z).reshape(712,3), 
cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
#ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
plt.show()
```

Error

```
 ax.plot_surface(np.array(x).reshape(712,3), np.array(y).reshape(712,3), np.array(z).reshape(712,3), cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
 ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 712 into shape (712,3)
```

Comment: why are you reshaping to 712,3?

Comment: just do the same without reshaqping? you divided each columns to x,y,z so each of them are (712,1)

Comment: Thanks @adirabargil, your help is highly appreciated and it solved the issue. but now I dont see any data in my plot

Comment: thats another issue... post a question represnting data sample with a plot as image, and excpected output